# Is there any performance gain from using type suffixes in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, types

Using type suffixes (like *0d* for a dual with value zero or *0f* for float) is sometimes necessary and often considered good style.

But has it any performance implications?

So calling a few million times

```
if (x == 0d) ...   or
if (x == 0.0) ...
```

will be as fast as

```
if (x == 0) ...
```

I suppose, the compiler will transform 0 once into 0.0, so it does not matter for performance. But since I saw it in quality code a few times, I'm not sure...

---

Added because of the comments: x is not an int its a double.

Comment: `x` being of type `int`?

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking it?

Comment: Only difference is when compiling, and even then almost none (if any). Only _possible_ difference is when you confuse the different types. For example, `0d` (`double`) is very much different than `0` (`int`) at compile and runtime.

Comment: What does the IL look like?

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Keep in mind that premature optimization usually is overrated and can easily make your code difficult to read. Unless you run into a case where this is actually causing problems I would recommend that you spend your time improving actual design or code problems.

Answer (score 4):

If you inspect IL code, you will find additional `conv` opcode when comparing to an `int` to  `0.0` literal

```
int x = 0;
Console.WriteLine (x == 0.0);

IL_0000:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0001:  stloc.0     // x
IL_0002:  ldloc.0     // x
IL_0003:  conv.r8     //<-- this is absent if literal is 0
IL_0004:  ldc.r8      00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
IL_000D:  ceq         
IL_000F:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
```

This is dua to a fact, that `Int32` `==` operator overload accepts `int` as a second parameter.

**Remarks:** compiled in LINQPad using Compiler optimization flag **on**.

**One big remark** don't do nano-optimizations until you are sure, that this is a bottle-neck. Such optimizations are usually  spoil code readability and as result - maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

Taken the hint of Ilya Ivanov, I inspected the IL code of a small sample program.

Ilya assumed x to be an integer.If this is the case he is absolutely right with his comment about the conversion (conv.r8). But the case I had in mind was if you compare a variable of type double with a double literal. 
**Does the type suffix make any difference in this case?**

**The answer is: NO!**

Let's look at this small program, comparing (d == 0) or alternatively (d == 0d):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double d = 0.0;

    if (d == 0)     // if (d == 0d)
        d = 1.23;

    Console.WriteLine(d);
}
```

Both versions compile into exactly the same IL-Code:

```
.method private hidebysig static 
    void Main (
        string[] args
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 48 (0x30)
    .maxstack 2
    .entrypoint
    .locals init (
        [0] float64 d,
        [1] bool CS$4$0000
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldc.r8 0.0
    IL_000a: stloc.0
    IL_000b: ldloc.0
    IL_000c: ldc.r8 0.0
    IL_0015: ceq
    IL_0017: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0018: ceq
    IL_001a: stloc.1
    IL_001b: ldloc.1
    IL_001c: brtrue.s IL_0028

    IL_001e: ldc.r8 1.23
    IL_0027: stloc.0

    IL_0028: ldloc.0
    IL_0029: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(float64)
    IL_002e: nop
    IL_002f: ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

And of course also the assembler code is the same.

So writing 0 instead of 0.0 or 0d is just fine...